# M2: Is `url_path` used for anything?

Tags: magento2, product-urls, magento-2.1.2, url-key

I'm working with a catalog in M2 that has been somehow migrated (don't know how). It has `url_path` migrated and has the form of `url_key` + `html`. This is causing the URL rewrites to create URLs that end with `http://example.com/.../.html.html`.

Looking a the DB and code, it looks like it's for bundle or configurable  products but still unclear what it is for. Removing them from simple and configurable products don't seem to have any affects.

Any ideas if `url_path` data is need for anything?

Comment: In the M2 sample-data product doesn't have any value for url_path. So I think deleting url_path values for a product should not harm. But for categories, it's important as they have hierarchies.

Comment: I can also confirm the issue if `url_path` has `[url-key].html` value then `url_rewrites` will be full of `.html.html` value. Seems to be the bug for me.

Answer (score 3):

`url_path` is deprecated, and could safely delete its data. I tested it in my Magento 2.3.2.

You could see the deprecated statement in the [offical github comment](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9113#issuecomment-488790088) and the [graphql-ce codes](https://github.com/magento/graphql-ce/pull/721/commits/7cc8c69d6ecb63cad8f3343905ddedbc513420cb).

```
url_path: String @deprecated(reason: "Use product's `canonical_url` or url rewrites instead")
```

Answer (score 2):

"**url_path**" is used for url rewrites generation. Even in Magento 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience Magento in products is using url_path to generate urls, but if we delete all url_path entries it uses url key instead. Actually sinse we cannot change it in admin it seams to better to delete it all. Sorry for not using comment, but i don't have enough rep points.

Comment: Now you have more 10